# Java import does not exist package

Tags: java

I have this folder structure:

```
MyProject 
    src/
      com/example/
        model/
        web/
    classes/
```

`src` for source code, `classes` for classes.

I was trying to compile a java file from web folder, and to do that I had to import one class from the model folder. I did that,but the compiler was saying:

> "package com.example.model.*; doesn't exist".

Eventually I managed to compile it with this command:

`C:\Users\dimit\Desktop\MyProject\beerV1>javac -classpath C:\Users\dimit\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.5\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Users\dimit\Desktop\MyProject\beerV1\classes -d classes src/com/example/web/BeerSelect.java`

But it looks kind of a bad. Is there any way to compile the java without adding classpath? I mean both web and model source codes are in the same package, why there is a problem in finding the `com.example.model.*;` package?

Here is the code

```
package com.example.model;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerExpert {

    public List getBrands(String color) {
        List<String> brands=new ArrayList<String>();
        if(color.equals("amber")) {
            brands.add("Jack Amber");
            brands.add("Red Moose");
        }else{
            brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");
            brands.add("Gout Stout");
        }
        return (brands);
    }
}
```

Comment: package com.example.web;
import com.example.model.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException  {

  
  String c=request.getParameter("color");
  List result=new BeerExpert().getBrands(c);
  Iterator it=result.iterator();
  PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
  while(it.hasNext() ) {
  out.println("<br>try "+it.next());

  }
 }
}

Comment: and what's the point of posting messed code as comment to own question instead of doing question edit?

Comment: When compiling, you should put `...\beerV1\src`, not `...\beerV1\classes`, on the classpath. And no, you cannot compile without setting classpath. --- But why don't you use an IDE? It makes compiling a breeze and it usually handles the classpath for you. And it comes with a very nice *helpful* editor that makes write code easier too. Highly recommended by most programmers.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i added the comment,it was my mistake.Sorry.